# Does the category of locally compact Hausdorff spaces with proper maps have products?

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, limits-and-colimits

nlab presents a [proof](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+compact+topological+space#categorytheoretic_properties) that the category of locally compact Hausdorff spaces does not admit infinite products in general. In particular it shows that there is no infinite product of $\mathbb{R}$, since  such a product would be a topological vector space, by the universal property of the projection maps, and it would also be a product in $\mathbb{R}\text{Vect}$.  It is known that every locally compact Hausdorff topological vector space is finite dimensional, see [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/locally-compact-topological-vector-spaces/) for example.

However since linear maps in $\mathbb{R}\text{Vect}$ are not in general proper, such a proof doesn't work in the case that you restrict to proper continuous maps between locally compact Hausdorff spaces.

I wanted to know if there is still a known counterexample that means that this category will not have products?

One reason that suggests to me they  might is that topological spaces with local homeomorphisms (étale maps) has products, and they are very weird; for example $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^2=∅$ in that category. It also massively restricts what maps can be onto compact spaces (they must come from a compact space, which is another 'intuition' for why it might have products.

Comment: Page 6 of Tyrone Cutler's note [here](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~tcutler/pdf/Elementary%20Homotopy%20Theory%20II%20-%20The%20Pointed%20Category.pdf) says the product may fail to exist since the projections can fail to be proper (but also remarks that nevertheless at least $\times$ is part of a non-Cartesian monoidal structure on the category of locally compact Hausdorff spaces with proper maps)

Comment: Just want to note - whereas products in the category of topological spaces and local homeomorphisms are indeed weird (there is no terminal object in fact), pullbacks there are quite nice.

Comment: @Emily I'm not sure that is quite right, it seems to be suggesting that the product would be the same as that in Top, and of course that product doesn't work, but I'm asking if there is a different topological space which is the product in this category. Note that for example, colimits must be different in this category (i.e. the coproduct of locally compact Hausdorff spaces in Top won't be the coproduct in this category, since the *-compactification must preserve colimits into KHaus, and those are just disjoint unions)

Comment: @OddlyAsymmetric Hmm, now that you mention it I'm not sure whether Tyrone means that the usual product space isn't the product in [LCHaus w/ proper maps] or if the projections failing to be proper _somehow_ imply that [LCHaus w/ proper maps] doesn't have products. (I feel like it's probably the former, but the note says "products in [LCHaus w/ proper maps] don't exist", so again I'm not really sure...). Maybe you could try asking them if they could elaborate (Or hopefully they'll simply see this question :), I've seen Tyrone here (or on MSE?) before)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose $X,Y$ are locally compact Hausdorff spaces admitting a product $X\otimes Y$ in the category $\mathcal{H}$ of all such spaces. If one of $X,Y$ is empty, then $X\otimes Y$ exists, so I'll assume that neither is.

Then the points of $X\otimes Y$ are exactly the maps $\ast\rightarrow X\otimes Y$. Since $X\otimes Y$ is Hausdorff, any such map is proper. Because of this, both of the categorical projections
$$X\xleftarrow{\pi_X} X\otimes Y\xrightarrow{\pi_Y}Y$$
are surjective. They are continuous and proper by assumption.

Working now in $Top$, the category of all spaces, we have the Tychonoff product $X\times Y$ and an induced map
$$\theta:X\otimes Y\rightarrow X\times Y$$
factoring the projections. By the above observation, $\theta$ is surjective.

> **Lemma**: Suppose that $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow C$ are maps of spaces $A,B,C$. If $f$ is surjective and $g\circ f$ is proper, then $g$ is proper. $\quad\blacksquare$

Apply the lemma to the composite
$$pr_X\circ \theta=\pi_X$$
to conclude that $pr_X$ is proper. This is only possible if $Y$ is compact. Similarly, $X$ must also be compact.

Of course, if $X,Y$ are compact, then the product $X\otimes Y$ exists in $\mathcal{H}$ and is given by the Tychonoff product $X\times Y$.

> If $X,Y$ are locally compact Hausdorff and nonempty, then the product $X\otimes Y$ exists in $\mathcal{H}$ if and only if both $X,Y$ are compact.

Comment: A point of $X\times Y$ is a pair of maps $X\leftarrow *\rightarrow Y$, and this is exactly a point of $X\otimes Y$. I am assuming $X,Y$ are nonempty.

Comment: Then doesn't this tell us $\theta$ is a bijection? Also, when you say "the above observation", it's not clear which sentence you mean. It could be anything prior in the post, because it's not signposted

Comment: @Tyrone, thanks for this, I was thinking a proof might go something like this. In the note Emily mentioned, you say that it does have coproducts, yet it won't be the same coproduct as in Top, because then one-point compactification wouldn't preserve it, and one-point compactification is left adjoint to the inclusion of KHaus. Could you expand on that point?

Comment: I think $\mathcal{H}$ has only *finite* coproducts. I agree that the statement you are referring to in the note is poorly worded. I didn't mean to mislead. However, I'm not sure I follow your comment about the inclusion of $KHaus$. If $Y$ is compact and $X$ is not, then there is no proper map $X\rightarrow Y$.

Comment: My point is any map $X \to Y$ with $Y$ compact must have come from a compact space, so if you define $*:LKHaus \to KHaus$ by one-point compactification on non-compact objects, identity on compact objects, and by the obvious definition on morphisms (the only non-obvious case is when $X$ is compact, $Y$ is not, but then you can just post compose with the inclusion $Y \to Y^{*}$, and can check this is functorial). Hence you have $*$ is left adjoint to the inclusion, so will need to preserve coproducts. You will therefore need $(X \oplus Y)^{*}=X^{*} \sqcup Y^{*}$ but it's not clear to me how.

Comment: In fact I'm fairly sure that's a proof that $\mathcal{H}$ won't have finite coproducts: if $X$ or $Y$ are both not compact, then $X \oplus Y$ cannot be compact, and so must be $X^{*} \sqcup Y^{*}$ minus a point, leaving wlog $X^{*}$ intact. Since the coprojection $\iota_{X}$ is proper, and the inclusion into the disjoint sum is an extension of it $X$ must have been compact after all.

Comment: But these definitions do not yield an adjunction because if $K$ is compact and $X$ is noncompact, then $\mathcal{H}(X,K)$ is empty while $\mathcal{K}(X_\infty,K)$ is not.

Comment: What you can do is this: let $\mathcal{K}^*$ be the category with objects *pointed* compact $T_2$ spaces. A morphism in $\mathcal{K}^*$ is a map $f:K\rightarrow L$ such that $f^{-1}(\ast_L)=\{\ast_K\}$. One-point compactification determines an adjunction $\mathcal{H}\dashv\mathcal{K}^*$. The right adjoint deletes the basepoint. Both categories have finite coproducts: in $\mathcal{H}$ these are disjoint unions and in $\mathcal{K}^*$ they are wedge sums. Both categories have monoidal products (Tychonoff vs. smash). Both finite coproducts and monoidal products are preserved by the adjunction.